# Credit-card fraud data set wanted

Tags: data-request, china

Recently [I found this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8361343) about the use of [random forests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) to detect and prevent credit card fraud.

In this paper the authors use a dataset with more than 30 million records from a Chinese e-commerce company. Does anyone know if this specific dataset is available? I'm a grad in computer science and I'm currently studying this subject. This database will help me a lot.

Comment: Hi Evilmaax, not everyone will have the access to the link provided, Could you please add more information on the dataset you need.

Comment: Everyone can have access thanks to sci-hub: https://sci-hub.st/https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8361343

Comment: @Evilmaax have you tried contacting them? Is there anything important/more specific about this dataset other than 30m, Chinese, e-comm?

Comment: @albert Actually, I looking for a credit card (fraud and true transactions) database with more than 200k records at least, anyone; except that one provided by european cardholders comprising 3 months of 2014 (this one I already using, I need something else).

Comment: @Evilmaax so it would be ideal for the site and for you, if you added this to your question. The question is extremely vague, particularly the title.

Comment: you should also contact the authors of that paper and see if they will share with you.

Comment: @albert I tried, but no responses so far